# Why, when loaded into RAM, does my netcdf file larger than the actual file size?

Tags: python, netcdf

I have a netCDF file that is 1.1 Gb sitting on my hard drive, yet, when I load the main variable into memory, it is taking up more than my 8 Gb of RAM.

It is a very large matrix (48, 3105, 7025), which python itself won't load on my machine ( np.ones((48, 3105, 7025)) ), but is there any particular reason? If I load in one slice, I am looking at 21,812,625 around 21 Mb, which adds up to the original file size.

What is python doing that takes up so much memory, and is there a way around it?

Comment: How are you loading the file? Python objects use more memory than just the bytes for the data they reference. (For example, an `int` object uses 24(?) bytes beyond what it needs to actually store the integer value itself.)

Comment: Yeah, it's dtype is float32, and unfortunately it needs to be.

Comment: Is the file compressed? NetCDF files can be compressed easily, you can check if it's compressed or not with cdo sinfo.

Comment: Without minimal sample code that actually replicates the problem, we're only going to be guessing as to what causes the problem. First guess is that while you're only asking for a slice, it's a slice across many (if not all) of the compressed chunks in the file, necessitating uncompressing it all (3.9GB at least)